# BLDC torque and speed control

Tags: brushless-dc-motor, torque, speed

Actually I drive a DC motor in speed and torque at the same time. I would like to know if there is a solution to do the same with a BLDC. The motor is 50W max.

I can make a custom PCB to use a BLDC driver, hall effect input and analog input.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "drive .. in speed and torque at the same time"? You can do almost anything with a BLDC that you can do with a DC brush motor, as long as you have the right controller.

Comment: _"The motor is 50W max."_ - exactly which motor is it, and what  is the application?